# SHEmptyRecycleBin in VB6 doesn't do anything

Tags: vb6, recycle-bin

I'm trying to empty the recycle bin as part of a process that is freeing up hard disk space.  He is the code I've got so far.  At the top of my class:

```
Private Declare Function SHEmptyRecycleBin Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHEmptyRecycleBinA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal pszRootPath As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon Lib "shell32.dll" () As Long
```

Then in the hard disk clean up function:

```
SHEmptyRecycleBin(Empty, vbNullString, 0)
SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon
```

I also tried this:

```
Dim lRetVal As Long
lRetVal = 0
lRetVal = SHEmptyRecycleBin(Empty, vbNullString, 0)
```

But it's returning a zero, indicating success.  Has anyone ever used this function before, or have an ideas about why it wouldn't work?  This code is being run from within an ActiveX dll, if that matters.

**EDIT**

Well, I think I must've misread or misunderstood something before, because I think whatever examples I looked at gave me the impression the confirmation window would not be called by using 0 for the last variable. I tried this code:

```
Const SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = &H1
Call SHEmptyRecycleBin(0, vbNullString, SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION)
```

...and it still doesn't work.  However, if I use this code in the .exe that is calling the ActiveX dll:

```
Const SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = &H1
lRetVal = SHEmptyRecycleBin(Empty, vbNullString, SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION)
```

...it works.  I can't figure out why it works in the .exe and not the .dll though, and I'd rather keep all the code in the .dll if possible.

Comment: I hope this program is only for your own use.  It isn't nice for a program to take control of something like this away from the user.  I keep my Recycle Bin clean but a lot of users rely on things "hanging there" in case they change their minds about a delete operation - the whole reason we have a Recycle Bin.

Comment: It seems to work here from a main program however.  Note that "Empty" for the hWnd parameter works, but an explicit 0 is probably a better choice.  I get the prompt dialog though nothing there tells the user they're being asked to Ok emptying of the Recycle Bin.

Comment: A few points.  I am using this to clean up a server that is only used by admins, not actual users.  I figured out what the problem is.  This is being run as a scheduled task, under a user account that does things in the background, so the confirmation window (which I didn't realize existed) isn't showing up.  I presume the call is terminating with a cancel, and thus returns 0 because it canceled okay.  I guess I need to find out if I can programmatically confirm the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [sample](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/CF50E5E11277B90CB13684D62FAF4CF8.html).

Basicly `SHEmptyRecycleBin 0, vbNullString, 0` or `Call SHEmptyRecycleBin(0, vbNullString, 0)` should be ok, but they are passing an actual `hwnd` for function UI to use as owner window.